# L2S querying child objects from parent (in 1-many relationship)

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

```
var obj = from r in db.ParentTables
          where r.ChildTable.Count > 0 // &&  How can we get the Child table data by parsing value by query string.? for eg: r.ChildTable.Language= English
          select r;
```

I need to maintain the returned query as r i.e. IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question right, are looking for something like this

```
var obj = from r in db.ParentTables
          where r.ChildTable.Any(c => c.Language = "English")
          select r;
```

Comment: I am sorry but that didn't work... It is returning all child records even if they don't match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = from r in db.ParentTables
          where r.ChildTable.Any(c => c.Count() > 0 && c.Language == "English")
          select r;
```